# Tag wiki excerpts in popups; time from edit to display

Tags: support, tag-wiki, popups

How often are tag wiki excerpts migrated into the tag popup windows?

I ask because I edited several tags and didn't notice any change to the text produced in the popups (either showing the old lower-quality text, or nothing at all in the case that there was previously no tag wiki).

I suppose it could be a browser caching issue. Theoretically. But if so, it's a puzzling one. I'd be much happier if it was something more prosaic like “a cron job rebuilds it daily” or something equally mundane. After all, now that so many people can propose tag edits, the cost of keeping this previously largely-static part of the site up to date would be rather high.

Answer (score 2):

There is about a 1 hour delay there, we cache the popups quite heavily cause they currently depend on a fairly expensive query.

We plan to improve this, just have not gotten around to it yet.

Comment: It seems rather longer than that at the moment; I cite as evidence the `tk` tag on SO, for which my update was approved yesterday and yet where it's not yet propagated over 19 hours later. I've tried with two browsers, one of which I don't use for SO normally so it had nothing to speak of cached (and I know my network doesn't have any proxies in the mix). Something else is going on…

Comment: +1 though for answering the main part of the question.